# Swift NSViewController responds to mouseDown event, but not keyDown event

Tags: cocoa

I am trying to create an application for OS X using Swift and Cocoa. I want the application to respond to key events without the focus being on/in a text field. I created a new Cocoa project with storyboards in Xcode, and have modified the ViewController.swift class to the following:

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    override func mouseDown(theEvent: NSEvent) {
        println( "Mouse Clicked" )
    }

    override func keyDown(theEvent: NSEvent) {
        println( "Key Pressed" )
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override var representedObject: AnyObject? {
        didSet {
        }
    }

}
```

When I run the program, I get console output when I click on the window, but I don't get any console output when I press any keys.

So my questions are: **Why does my program respond to mouse events but not key events? What extra steps do I need to do for key events to work as the mouse events do?**

It appears that my view controller is in the responder chain since it intercepts the mouse events, so that doesn't seem to be the problem. I have found other answers on here on SE saying I need to subclass the NSView or NSWindow class. Is it possible to get key events without doing that?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: In addition to the accepted answer, [Swift - Capture keydown from NSViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32446978/swift-capture-keydown-from-nsviewcontroller/32447474) is a great, clear solution.

Comment: could you please provide your code for subclassing NSView? I need to do the same thing I believe. I am trying to get arrow keys when pressed.

Comment: The best answer to this question is in here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32446978/swift-capture-keydown-from-nsviewcontroller/32447474  I am posting this because none of the examples given really helped me and I got a really simple answer in the post above that worked, even in Xcode 8 and Swift 3.

Comment: @jvarela That is a good link. Thanks. I'll update my question to link to it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The difference you observed originates from the fact that Cocoa handles mouse events and keyboard events somewhat differently. In early stage of the event dispatching process, all events are sent to the `NSWindow` object by system. For mouse events, `NSWindow` forwards them to the view on which user clicked; for keyboard events, `NSWindow` will forward them to the **first responder** of current key window.

The initial first responder of an `NSWindow` is the window itself. When user clicks on an `NSView`, `NSWindow` will *try* to make that view the first responder by sending an `acceptsFirstResponder` message. If it returns `YES`, the clicked view will become first responder.

The "gotcha," however, is that `acceptsFirstResponder` returns `NO` by default. As a plain `NSView` won't become the first responder, it won't receive keyboard events. So the easiest solution is to subclass your `NSView`, override `acceptsFirstResponder` to return `YES`.